# Where I can get all the commands related to Web Driver / Selenium 2?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java

I am not able to find all the commands for WebDriver / Selenium 2. Where can I get them?

Answer (score 5):

[Java](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/)

[Ruby](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/Selenium)

[Python](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html)

[.Net](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/)

[JavaScript](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/)

Majority of the remote commands can be found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/650a1ab4fe3f0363cde72d8e0202e61e3f713acd/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java).  <sub>Ex. http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session for session</sub>

This will contain all of the functions that Selenium uses.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down to: "Selenium-WebDriver API Commands and Operations"

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Per https://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-methods

```
get()              # The most common, get request to load the page
getCurrentUrl();   # The URL
getTitle()         # Page title
findElements()     # HTML elements on the page
findElement()      # HTML element on the page
getPageSource()    # HTML DOM code
close()            # Close window
quit()             # Close browser

getWindowHandle()  # Used in switching window
getWindowHandles() # Used in switching windows
navigate()         # browser history
manage()           # options
```